# difference between updateOne and update when pushing an array in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

after reading:

```
DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
```

I've replaced collection.update by collection.updateOne that give me another result when pushing an array in an array.

I have tried to use findOneAndUpdate but I obtain the same result

my code before

```
Coupon.update({ "_id": couponId }, { $push: { "usersUsedCoupons": [userId, 1] } }, 
          { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true }).exec(function (err, info) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("info : ", info);
            return info;
          }
        });
      }
```

this was pushing [userId, 1] to the end of the array

my code after

```
Coupon.updateOne({ "_id": couponId }, { $push: { "usersUsedCoupons": [userId, 1] } }, 
          { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true }).exec(function (err, info) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("info : ", info);
            return info;
          }
        });
```

now it push each index of the array [userId, 1] in a different index of parent array 
like:

0: userId,

1: 1

I expect to have the same behavior as Coupon.update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution updateOne is pushing each index of the array in a different index in contrary with update so
using update:

```
[userId, 1]
```

using updateOne:

```
[[userId, 1]]
```

**UPDATE**

After updating to mongoose ^6.3.6
now for exemple we push a single index

```
$push: {
    status: {
       date: new Date(),
       branchId: dn.branchId,
       branchName: dn.branchName,
       actualStatus: dn.actualStatus,
    },
 }
```

for multiple index:

```
$push: {
    status: {
        $each: [
            {
                date: new Date(),
                branchId: dn.branchId,
                branchName: dn.branchName,
                actualStatus: dn.actualStatus
            },
            {
                date: new Date(),
                branchId: dn.branchId,
                branchName: dn.branchName,
                actualStatus: dn.actualStatus
            }
        ]
    }
}
```